# How to make resizable triangle in android

Tags: android, canvas, android-custom-view

I want to make resizable triangle like facility provide into paint or other software, may simple triangle draw and also move using coordinate but how I can resize this triangle I don’t know can anybody help me for this task.

i want like this
[image]

Making of the triangle into canvas is so easy here using this function may draw triangle into canvas

```
public void drawTriangle(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, int x, int y, int width) {   
    int halfWidth = width / 2;

    Path path = new Path();
    path.moveTo(x, y - halfWidth);
    path.lineTo(x - halfWidth, y + halfWidth); 
    path.lineTo(x + halfWidth, y + halfWidth); 
    path.lineTo(x, y - halfWidth); 
    path.close();

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
}
```